# Java App to receive http PUT and Get request

Tags: java, http, servlets

I am looking for advice on how to go about writing a small and simple application that will receive http GET and http PUT request, process the data (simple text files) and respond.

I have all ready done this using threads and sockets but there must be a simpler and more efficient way. Also when I run my application using wireshark I am not convince I am using the http protocol as I should be.

Thanks
Alexis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tiny Java Web Server. (http://tjws.sourceforge.net/)

Alternatively, if you are using Java 6 or later, you can use the Http server API.

Comment: Thanks for that. HttpServer API solved it. This example help me to get started: http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/10/simple-http-server-java.html

Answer (score 1):

I used [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) for similar purposes - it provides functionality for HTTP server and client parts implementation. It's easy to learn and use.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider embedding a webserver like Jetty (start/stop it from java app) if you want to get the full benefits of HTTP parsing.